# Struts2 -- Exception starting filter struts

Tags: struts2

I have a similar question to the one I just asked.  I'm trying to start my Struts2 application, but this time I just downloaded and added javassist-3.0.jar to my classpath (and /WEB-INF/lib) and I still get this same error.  Any advice out there?  Here are the filter references in my web.xml.

```
<filter>
    <filter-name>struts2</filter-name>
    <filter-class>org.apache.struts2.dispatcher.FilterDispatcher</filter-class>
</filter>
<filter-mapping>
    <filter-name>struts2</filter-name>
    <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
</filter-mapping>
```

Here is the error in my console.

```
SEVERE: Exception starting filter struts2
java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException - Class: com.opensymphony.xwork2.inject.ContainerImpl$MethodInjector
File: ContainerImpl.java
Method: inject
Line: 295 - com/opensymphony/xwork2/inject/ContainerImpl.java:295:-1
    at org.apache.struts2.dispatcher.Dispatcher.init(Dispatcher.java:449)
    at org.apache.struts2.dispatcher.FilterDispatcher.init(FilterDispatcher.java:195)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterConfig.getFilter(ApplicationFilterConfig.java:275)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterConfig.setFilterDef(ApplicationFilterConfig.java:397)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterConfig.<init>(ApplicationFilterConfig.java:108)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.filterStart(StandardContext.java:3696)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.start(StandardContext.java:4343)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.start(ContainerBase.java:1045)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost.start(StandardHost.java:719)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.start(ContainerBase.java:1045)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngine.start(StandardEngine.java:443)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardService.start(StandardService.java:516)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardServer.start(StandardServer.java:710)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina.start(Catalina.java:566)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap.start(Bootstrap.java:288)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap.main(Bootstrap.java:413)
Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.inject.ContainerImpl$MethodInjector.inject(ContainerImpl.java:295)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.inject.ContainerImpl$ConstructorInjector.construct(ContainerImpl.java:431)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.inject.ContainerBuilder$5.create(ContainerBuilder.java:207)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.inject.Scope$2$1.create(Scope.java:51)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.inject.ContainerBuilder$3.create(ContainerBuilder.java:93)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.inject.ContainerBuilder$7.call(ContainerBuilder.java:487)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.inject.ContainerBuilder$7.call(ContainerBuilder.java:484)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.inject.ContainerImpl.callInContext(ContainerImpl.java:574)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.inject.ContainerBuilder.create(ContainerBuilder.java:484)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.config.impl.DefaultConfiguration.createBootstrapContainer(DefaultConfiguration.java:252)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.config.impl.DefaultConfiguration.reloadContainer(DefaultConfiguration.java:193)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.config.ConfigurationManager.getConfiguration(ConfigurationManager.java:66)
    at org.apache.struts2.dispatcher.Dispatcher.init_PreloadConfiguration(Dispatcher.java:390)
    at org.apache.struts2.dispatcher.Dispatcher.init(Dispatcher.java:436)
    ... 19 more
Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.inject.ContainerImpl$MethodInjector.inject(ContainerImpl.java:293)
    ... 32 more
Caused by: java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.ognl.OgnlValueStackFactory.setContainer(OgnlValueStackFactory.java:85)
    ... 37 more
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Javassist library is missing in classpath! Please add missed dependency!
    at ognl.OgnlRuntime.<clinit>(OgnlRuntime.java:168)
    ... 38 more
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: javassist.ClassPool
    at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader.loadClass(WebappClassLoader.java:1358)
    at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader.loadClass(WebappClassLoader.java:1204)
    at java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method)
    at java.lang.Class.forName(Unknown Source)
    at ognl.OgnlRuntime.<clinit>(OgnlRuntime.java:165)
    ... 38 more
```

Comment: You need to include S2 version, otherwise it becomes difficult to help diagnose.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I replaced all the jar files I had with the ones from another application I have that's working and doesn't have this issue.  This application works now.  I'm guessing there was some clash between jar files that was causing the problem.

Answer (score 2):

try this:

```
<filter>
        <filter-name>struts2</filter-name>
        <filter-class>org.apache.struts2.dispatcher.ng.filter.StrutsPrepareAndExecuteFilter</filter-class>
    </filter>
    <filter-mapping>
        <filter-name>struts2</filter-name>
        <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
    </filter-mapping>
```

**UPDATE 1**

please check, if you got all the dependencies included:

[image: struts2-core dependencies]

or if you are using maven:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.apache.struts</groupId>
    <artifactId>struts2-core</artifactId>
    <version>${struts.version}</version>
</dependency>
```

Comment: @Frank are you using maven or you should make sure at least all the dependencies on your classpath. see UPDATE 1

Answer (score 1):

**Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: javassist.ClassPool**

you need javassist-3.11.0.GA.jar on your WEB-INF/lib